# How can I generate age automatically when a date is selected from jdatechooser

Tags: java

```java
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {    
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    int YearNow = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(d));
    int YearBD = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(visitordob.getDate()));
    int Bd = YearNow - YearBD;
    jLabel.setText(Bd);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question and describe what problem you are facing. What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LocalDate` and `Period.between()`. Just remember to import them from `java.time`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(dob);
//Converting obtained Date object to LocalDate object
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zone = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate givenDate = zone.toLocalDate();
//Calculating the difference between given date to current date.
Period period = Period.between(givenDate, LocalDate.now());
System.out.print("Age: " + period.getYears());
```